# VB.NET RaiseEvent asking for expression

Tags: vb.net

I am learning about keyboard hooks in VB.NET and need help with an error. At first it told me I must change (Not (KeyDown) Is Nothing) & KeyUp to RaiseEvent because they are events, which I have done. But now it's telling me an ')' expression is expected, and I have no idea what that means. I've made it this far using VB.NET wikis and snippets of code and I'm quite proud of myself. I don't want this to flop now. Please help! There is an image of the error at the very bottom.

```
    Public Event KeyDown As KeyboardHookCallback

    Public Event KeyUp As KeyboardHookCallback
Private Function HookFunc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        If (nCode >= 0) Then
            Dim iwParam As Integer = wParam.ToInt32
            If ((iwParam = WM_KEYDOWN) _
        OrElse (iwParam = WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) Then
                If (Not RaiseEvent KeyDown Is Nothing) Then
                    RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), VKeys))
                End If

            End If

            If ((iwParam = WM_KEYUP) _
    OrElse (iwParam = WM_SYSKEYUP)) Then
                If (Not RaiseEvent KeyUp Is Nothing) Then
                    RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), VKeys))
                End If

            End If

        End If

        Return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function
```

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: 1) An expression is something that has a value, for example 5, or `x + y`. 2) I *suspect* that you are trying to find out if there is an event handler associated with the KeyUp event. I suggest that you get your code working before trying to add extra features like that.

Comment: It looks like an attempt to translate C# code.  Delete the If-statement, it is neither correct nor necessary.  Just plain RaiseEvent gets the job done.

Comment: The Microsoft [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/coding-conventions) documentation specifically states "Do not verify whether an event is Nothing (null) before you call the RaiseEvent method. RaiseEvent checks for Nothing before it raises the event."

Answer (score 1):

You should simply just raise the event.. If there is anything listening to it, it will run. If there isn't, no harm is done.

```
Public Event KeyDown As KeyboardHookCallback
Public Event KeyUp As KeyboardHookCallback

Private Function HookFunc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    If (nCode >= 0) Then
        Dim iwParam As Integer = wParam.ToInt32
        If ((iwParam = WM_KEYDOWN) OrElse (iwParam = WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) Then
            RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), VKeys))
        End If

        If ((iwParam = WM_KEYUP) OrElse (iwParam = WM_SYSKEYUP)) Then
            RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), VKeys))
        End If

    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```